# How to select data with group by and subquery calculations?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:
list_table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | c |

vt_table:

| id | list_id | amount | direction_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 20 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 12 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 15 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 23 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 20 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 | 20 | 2 |
| 7 | 1 | 18 | 1 |

I need this result:
amount (dir_id = 1 - dir_id = 2), list_id

| amount | list_id |
| --- | --- |
| 41 | 1 |
| 23 | 2 |
| 0 | 3 |

Amount is sum of all `amount` fields in table vt_table where direction_id = 1 minus sum of all `amount` fileds in table vt_table where direction_id = 2

And I need group this calculations by `list_id`, and if table have no rows with `list_id` 3, as example, amount must be `0`.

I'm trying to do it with this query:

```
SELECT vt.list_id
     , ((SELECT COALESCE(SUM(vt.amount), 0)
             FROM table_name       vt
             WHERE vt.direction_id = 1)
    -
        (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(vt.amount), 0)
             FROM table_name       vt
             WHERE direction_id = 2)) AS result
    FROM table_name vt
    GROUP BY vt.list_id
```

But I don't know how to group it correctly and make it so that if there were no entries for some `list_id`, then the amount was `0` for this `list_id`.

I use PostgreSQL 12.

[Here the examples](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7cfcf/7/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use `OUTER JOIN` with condition aggregate function with `COALESCE` fucntion.

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT l.id, 
     SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN vt.direction_id = 1 THEN vt.amount END,0)) - 
       SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN vt.direction_id = 2 THEN vt.amount END,0)) AS result
FROM table_name vt
RIGHT JOIN list l ON vt.list_id = l.id
GROUP BY l.id
ORDER BY l.id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7cfcf/25/0)**:

```
| id | result |
|----|--------|
|  1 |     41 |
|  2 |     23 |
|  3 |      0 |
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this, as a start:

```
SELECT vt.list_id
     , COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN direction_id = 1 THEN amount END), 0)
     - COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN direction_id = 2 THEN amount END), 0) AS result
  FROM table_name vt
 GROUP BY vt.list_id
;
```

Result using your fiddle:

| list_id | result |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 41 |
| 2 | 23 |

This just misses the cases where there are no `vt` rows for some list.

Use an outer join to address those cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN vt.direction_id = 1 THEN vt.amount ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN vt.direction_id = 2 THEN vt.amount ELSE 0 END) as amount,
    lt.id as list_id
    FROM  list_table lt
    LEFT OUTER JOIN vt_table vt
    ON   lt.id = vt.list_id
    GROUP BY lt.id
ORDER BY lt.id
```